# Singleton Serviced Component

Tags: c#, .net, com+, servicedcomponent

I am trying to implement a serviced component as a singleton.
Currently, my code is like this:

```
[assembly: ApplicationName("SingletonServicedComponent")]
[assembly: ApplicationActivation(ActivationOption.Server)]
[assembly: ApplicationAccessControl(false)]

[ComVisible(true)]
[JustInTimeActivation(true)]
[ComponentAccessControl(false)]
[ProgId("Singleton.ServicedComponent")]
[ObjectPooling(Enabled = true, MaxPoolSize = 1, MinPoolSize = 1, CreationTimeout = 5000)]
public sealed class SingletonServicedComponent : System.EnterpriseServices.ServicedComponent
{
    private int value = 0;

    protected override bool CanBePooled()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public int Increment()
    {
        return this.value++;
    }
}
```

I am following the pattern of having it pooled, with a minimum and maximum instance count of 1.
I signed my assembly and registered it with regasm and regsvcs. It shows up in Component Services console, and appears to be OK.
However, when I instantiate it in different applications, I don't seem to be getting the same instance.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!
I was getting an activation exception because I was not releasing (.Dispose(), = null) the instance I had, so other processes could not acquire a reference to it.